# Get the SQL Server option

Tags: jquery, sql-server

ALL,

Is there a way to get the value of `SET COUNT` option from the SQL Server?

I don't want to issue it if its already been set, and if I do set it I want to reset it after I'm done with the appropriate query execution.

So I'm just looking for a simple `SELECT` statement.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (512 & @@OPTIONS) = 512 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

returns 1 when NOCOUNT is ON and 0 otherwise

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are referring to the `NOCOUNT` SQL Server option instead of `COUNT`, right?

Here is a query [Determining SET Options for a Current Session in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1415/determining-set-options-for-a-current-session-in-sql-server/) that will reveal the options that you have for a current SQL Server session:

```
DECLARE @options INT

SELECT @options = @@OPTIONS

PRINT @options

IF ( (1 & @options) = 1 ) PRINT 'DISABLE_DEF_CNST_CHK' 
IF ( (2 & @options) = 2 ) PRINT 'IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS' 
IF ( (4 & @options) = 4 ) PRINT 'CURSOR_CLOSE_ON_COMMIT' 
IF ( (8 & @options) = 8 ) PRINT 'ANSI_WARNINGS' 
IF ( (16 & @options) = 16 ) PRINT 'ANSI_PADDING' 
IF ( (32 & @options) = 32 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULLS' 
IF ( (64 & @options) = 64 ) PRINT 'ARITHABORT' 
IF ( (128 & @options) = 128 ) PRINT 'ARITHIGNORE'
IF ( (256 & @options) = 256 ) PRINT 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' 
IF ( (512 & @options) = 512 ) PRINT 'NOCOUNT' 
IF ( (1024 & @options) = 1024 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON' 
IF ( (2048 & @options) = 2048 ) PRINT 'ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF' 
IF ( (4096 & @options) = 4096 ) PRINT 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL' 
IF ( (8192 & @options) = 8192 ) PRINT 'NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT' 
IF ( (16384 & @options) = 16384 ) PRINT 'XACT_ABORT'
```

As you can see the options are flag values, which when processed through bit-wise ANDing will reveal the individual options applied to your session.